# How to give correct size to form inside popover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a form inside a popover (I'm using Bootstrap but the problem could be reproduced even using a simple CSS grid made by hand).

```
.popover
  form.form-horizontal
    .form-group
      label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='inputEmail3') Email
      .col-sm-10
        input#inputEmail3.form-control(type='email', placeholder='Email')
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/GpoxZz

The problem is that the form can't set its size correctly when inside a popover and then I get some unwanted effect.
For example, the labels are cut, as well as any other element without a width defined by CSS.

[image]
*The label is cut*

I can't set the width using CSS because on my app the labels are generated by the backend and I don't know the length of them.
How can I avoid the form from being so thin without manually setting the `width` by CSS?

> ## Clarification
>
> I'm not trying to fix just this little silly problem, I'm trying to
>   understand why this happens and I want to find a reliable solution to
>   the problem.
>
> Please don't post answer asking me to use javascript, adding paddings,
>   setting widths and so on. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you replace the `width` property with a `padding` property? would that have any effect?

Comment: how about setting popover `max-width` to 100%

Comment: @Rotan075 no it doesn't, feel free to edit my codepen if you make it work

Comment: @Amitsingh nothing changes at all, the `initial` value of `max-width` is already `100%`

Comment: your codepen seems to work fine

Comment: @Amitsingh I've added a screenshot of the problem

Comment: what am I wondering is, your `max-width` you set it to `initial`, but with that you do not set the actual `width` of the popover. Because if you just add: `width 100%` to your popover CSS class it works fine right? @FezVrasta

Comment: @Rotan075 no I have added `max-width initial` to override the max-width set by Bootstrap. Setting `width 100%` doesn't change anything.

Comment: i think you are trying to put a car inside a box

Comment: the problem is if you put heavy or large things inside a box than it will create a problem better put the `width` of popover in `px`

Comment: @Amitsingh I have already explained why I can't set the width, I just want the CSS to automatically fit the form. If you don't know the solution it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very quick solution that you can try is by adding the `word-break` CSS property.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQrzgG)

```
.popover {
  display: block;
  max-width: initial;
  margin: 20px;
}
.popover .form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.popover .form-horizontal .control-label {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.popover .col-sm-2 {
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

In that case you do not have to modify your width properties. Please keep in mind that the `word-break` [does not work](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break) with older opera browsers.

Still recommending that you should change the size of the label and the input field because your label now (set by Bootstrap class) is 16% of the total width while the input has 83% width. Anyways I hope it helps you.

**--EDIT--**

I know that you do not want to tweak the width of the objects, but I can not find any other solution than modifying it. I created a small JS code that checks how much character there are within a label and change the width of the label and input fields. Perhaps you can try something like that.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQrzgG)

```
var labelText = $(".test").text()
var lengthLabel = labelText.length;

if(lengthLabel > 6){
  $('.popover .form-horizontal .control-label').css('width','40%');
  $('.popover .col-sm-10').css('width','60%');
}
```

Comment: If I use a word longer than `password` (eg: `mylongpassword`) the problem occurs again :(

Comment: Yep, I think you do not have any other choice to actually tweak the width property of the label and input. You can also do this by using some kind of JS code. Look at my modified code @FezVrasta

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you.

CSS:

```
.popover
 display block
 max-width initial

.form-horizontal
 margin-left 4px;
 margin-right 30px;

.control-label
 text-align left;
 margin-left 1px;
```

Jade:

```
.popover
 form.form-horizontal
   .form-group
      label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='inputEmail3') Email
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputEmail3.form-control(type='email', placeholder='Email')
   .form-group
      label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='inputPassword3') Password
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputPassword3.form-control(type='password',
                                          placeholder='Password')
   .form-group
      .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
      .checkbox
       label
       input(type='checkbox') |  Remember me
   .form-group
      .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
       button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Sign in
```

http://codepen.io/har_kaur17/pen/LpGmRK

Comment: @FezVrasta then u can use `form(role="form")` instead of `form.form-horizontal`.http://codepen.io/har_kaur17/pen/LpGmRK

Comment: and remove `.form-horizontal` class.

Comment: *I want* the form to be horizontal!